# How to validate 'hours' field in 'project.task.work' module

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to validate 'hours' field that must not be more than 24hr.For that validation I wrote one function for that on my code is.

'hours': fields.float('Time Spent')

class task_timemanage(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'project.task.work'

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('hours')
def check_timing(self):
    self.r=0
    if self.hours > 00.00:
        if self.hours > 23.59:
            self.hours == self.r
            raise Warning('Please Enter the valid time')
    if self.hours < 0:
        self.hours == 0
        raise Warning('Please Enter the valid time')
```

The function is working fine the problem is

Example: The time is 11:30 for this My function is working.
If will give 11:72 also is working.here the minutes are not be more that 11:59.So kindly please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can change the condition to check

@api.multi
@api.onchange('hours')
def check_timing(self):
    self.r=0
    hours = str(self.hour)
    hour = int(hours.split(".")[0])
    minutes = int(hours.split(".")[1])
    if hour and minutes and hour <= 23 and minutes <= 59:
       #do your code
       pass
    else:
       raise Warning('Please Enter the valid time')
```

Comment: what 'hour' here ? 'hours' is filed of 'project.task.work'.What about 'hour'

Comment: Instead of 'hours' I need to use 'hour'.I changed the both places it's working Fine.

Comment: Thank! you Soo much